# Why don't we need an extra pair of parentheses around JavaScript function definition in some cases?

Tags: javascript

The following code doesn't work due to syntax error.

```
function() {
    alert('foo')
}()
```

JSFiddle URL for the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/qr2fr/

This code can be fixed by adding an extra pair of parentheses around the function definition in the following manner.

```
(function() {
    alert('foo')
})()
```

JSFiddle URL for the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/t6sJs/

However, the following JavaScript code works correctly and alerts the string "foo" without the extra pair of parentheses around the function definition.

```
var a = function() {
    alert('foo')
}()
```

JSFiddle URL for above code: http://jsfiddle.net/qLKsq/

Why does this code work without the extra pair of parentheses around the function definition?

Comment: This is the difference between declaration and expression, if the compiler is already in expression mode, you don't need to tell it to switch.

Comment: JS uses near identical syntax for function declarations and expressions. Your first is (or would be) a declaration, but it's missing the name. The others are part of an expression, so they can be anonymous.

Comment: [ECMAScript 12.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.4): "[A]n *ExpressionStatement* cannot start with the `function` keyword because that might make it ambiguous with a *FunctionDeclaration*." All of the Statement types are listed in [section 12](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12); an ExpressionStatement is a Statement that is an expression. Using an open parenthesis unambiguously starts expression. In other contexts, the ECMAScript grammar necessitates an expression, so no disambiguation is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to define a function in JavaScript.

A *declaration* (which is evaluated at compile time) and a *expression* (which is evaluated at runtime).

You can immediately involve a expression, but not a declaration.

The immediate preceding content determines if `function` is a expression or a declaration.

`(` makes it a expression. `=` makes it a expression. "Nothing"  makes it a declaration.

Comment: Using the `Function` constructor might be considered a third, though I suppose it's ultimately part of an expression.

Answer (score 2):

The `}()` is only valid if the function has been forced to be an expression. You will commonly see `(function(){...})()` to achieve this, though penny-pinchers might use `!function(){...}()` to save a byte (at the expense of an operation). Similarly, `var a = ...` takes the operand as an expression, so `}()` works.